# PHP prepend object in array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array `$post_types` with objects:

```
Array
(
  [vegetables] => WP_Post_Type Object
    (
        [name] => sports
        [label] => Sports
        [taxonomies] => Array
            (
                [0] => country
                [1] => type
            )

        [has_archive] => 1
        [show_in_rest] => 1
    )

    [fruits] => WP_Post_Type Object
      (
          [name] => fruits
          [label] => Fruits
          [taxonomies] => Array
              (
                  [0] => color
                  [1] => taste
                  [2] => origin
              )
          [has_archive] => 1
          [show_in_rest] => 1
      )
)
```

And I want to prepend the object from array `$prepend` into it:

```
Array
(
  [post] => WP_Post_Type Object
    (
        [name] => post
        [label] => Post
        [taxonomies] => Array
            (
                [0] => categories
                [1] => tags
            )

        [has_archive] => 1
        [show_in_rest] => 1
    )
)
```

I tried the following:

`$post_types[] = $prepend`

This adds it to the end of the `$post_types` array and it wraps an array with index 0 around it like so:

```
[0] => Array
  (
    [post] => WP_Post_Type Object
    ...
   )
...
```

I also tried `array_unshift($post_types , $prepend);`

It adds it to the beginning, but again wraps it in `array`. How can I add

```
[post] => WP_Post_Type Object
  (
    [name] => post
    [label] => Post
    ...
```

to `$post_types` without having the `[0] => array( ...`  wrapped around `[post] => WP_Post_Type Object ...` ?

I also tried `array_unshift($post_types, array_column($prepend, 'post'))` but adds an empty array.

Comment: `array_unshift` can't maintain the key "post". You'd have to write a piece of custom code, eg. build your target array from scratch and add the elements in the desired format and order (and with the key you want).

Comment: `$post_types['post'] = $prepend['post'];` Give the new occurance the key name you want or it will have to add a numeric key

Comment: `array_merge()` doesn't work?

Comment: `array_merge(['post'=>$prepend['post']], $post_types)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to "simply" merge the two arrays:

```
$post_types = array_merge($prepend, $post_types);
```